# when viewing the nerdtree window, how can i widen it?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I know if i have a horizontal pane at the bottom I can write something like

```
copen 50
```

and make it taller.  How can i make a vertical pane *wider*?

[image]

Comment: Hey abbood, I've deleted your comment, but I wanted to let you (a) we work very hard to foster a kind and friendly environment on [vi.se], and (b) you're welcome to ask why the -1, here or on meta—just remember no one is obligated to justify their voting. It also is not a comment on you or your expertise.

Answer (score 4):

In the Vim vocabulary what you call a "pane" is actually a "window" and the window you want to resize has nothing particular so [`:h window-resize`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#window-resize) should give you all you need, especially:

```
                        *CTRL-W_>*
CTRL-W >    Increase current window width by N (default 1).
```

So <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>></kbd> will increase the window size once and <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>></kbd> will do the same thing 10 times.

If you need to change the size in a script you want to read [`:h :wincmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd) which allows you do to the same thing as the <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd> normal commands.

---

Also `:copen` probably doesn't do what you think: it opens a window containing the quickfix list. If you want to open a vertical split you probably want `:split`  or <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>